# Transparent Background in Front of Another Background

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs that are layered; one in front (z-index:1), and one in back (z-index:-1). I would like the DIV in front to have a 'background-color: transparent', and the DIV in back to have a 'background-color: grey'.

The problem is the transparent color just shows grey (which is expected I suppose), so both DIVs display as one color. Is there a way to have an inner DIV that has a transparent color, and then a larger DIV around it that has a different background color wherever there isn't overlap?

Comment: so the answer of your second question is to pick your first example and make the bottom div larger, no ? ... can elaborate what you want ?

Comment: No matter how big the bottom DIV is, the top DIV will still just show its background color as it is transparent.

Comment: i mean you make the bottom bigger and you remove the transparent background from the top one ... can you draw something to explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```css
body {
 background:url(https://lorempixel.com/g/1000/800/) center/cover;
}

.container {
  margin:50px;
  padding:20px;
  --c:linear-gradient(red,red);
  background-image:var(--c),var(--c),var(--c),var(--c);
  background-size:30px 100%,100% 30px;
  background-position:left, top,right,bottom;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
  right:30px;
  bottom:30px;
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae mollis nisi. Mauris vestibulum ac lacus ac vulputate. Maecenas molestie ex dolor, et aliquet augue varius sit amet. Vivamus eleifend nisl nulla, a pellentesque ipsum pharetra eget. Curabitur tincidunt non nibh vitae convallis. Nunc magna 
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```